Trimming direction on climb out and descent to maintain an airspeed
What direction do I trim in order to catch an airspeed with the control stick while on the approach in the circuit pattern? When I normally trim out the control pressures while in the region of normal command it’s simple. see I am on the upwind of the departure leg if I push the nose down and I dream nose down by pushing the trim wheel forward I relieve the push down pressure from the control stick
But if I’m on the descent now it gets a little tricky especially in the traffic pattern down wind, base and approach,were we go into slow flight and region of reverse command I initially push the control stick to an attitude that gives me a higher speed, now what do I do to catch that speed when I get that speed? Do I trim nose down or do I trim nose up after getting that speed?

Thanks guys but do you guys think it’s wrong to do this  I pulled the trim wheel backward for a nose up attitude after pushing the control stick forward to just pass 80 knots in order to get 75 knots for my short final and just waited to see if the attitude and speed settles and it worked, I just now player with the throttle to maintain height as the runway got closer. It got the job done but is this wrong practice?

One- are you really in the region of reverse command at any point before you begin your landing flare?  May vary from one a/c to another.  Also w/ pilot technique, and w/ particular situation (i.e. short/ soft field landing, vs normal, vs gusty crosswind...)
Two-- your a/c's tendency to pitch to a higher or lower a-o-a (i.e. a lower or higher airspeed) as you change power will likely be the dominant issue as far as trim is concerned.
Three-- once you obtain any given desired airspeed, and capture that speed via stick/yoke inputs, the way you maintain that airspeed w/o stick/yoke pressure is simply to trim the stick/yoke pressure to zero.  If pushing, trim nose-down till the stick/yoke pressure goes to zero, and if pulling, trim nose-up till the stick-yoke pressure goes to zero.
Four-- keep in mind that for a normal, stable, aircraft, the "region of reverse command" just means that your sink rate will increase if you slow down without adding power.  It doesn't mean that you'll need less back pressure, or possibly even some forward pressure on the stick/yoke to fly slower without changing the throttle position.  For a normal, stable, aircraft, even in the region of reversed command, starting from any trimmed airspeed, to slow down you need to move the stick/yoke aft by holding aft pressure on the stick/yoke, and to speed up you need to move the stick/yoke forward by holding forward pressure on the stick/yoke.  So apply that pressure on the stick/yoke as needed, and then trim it away.  There won't be anything fundamentally different in the region of reversed command, than in the region of normal command.

Elevator trim sets the hands free angle of attack the airplane will seek on its own, for a given weight, center of gravity, and power configuration. In the absence of an angle-of-attack indicator, we use airspeed as a proxy for angle of attack, since they are directly related.
You generally let the trim do most of the work of holding a desirable pitch attitude for you, except for short term maneuvering inputs. So you should be in the habit of trimming out control pressures to let the airplane do the work of holding a speed/attitude for any case where you need the airplane to fly like that for more than a short time, say, 15 to 30 seconds. That way, if your attention is diverted and you relax your vigilance momentarily, no worries, as the plane will hold the speed/attitude you want largely on its own except for minor deviations due to turbulence or some such. You should think of the trim wheel as a hands-free speed control dial.
So if you're at, say, 70 kt and you are holding forward stick pressure to keep the nose from rising and the airplane slowing down, you trim nose down until the nose stays where you want it hands off. This leaves you free to pay attention to other things while you fly. Don't over think it. If you are holding forward pressure, trim ND, if back pressure trim NU until the nose attitude and speed stay where you want them without your input.
With tractor engine power planes with the engine in the nose, there is an added complication you must account for. Changes in power affect trim, either because the thrust line is above or below the center of mass and causes pitching moments, or because the increase in propeller wash over the tail increases the tail's effectiveness. Generally the change in tail effectiveness dominates, and you find that an increase in power changes trim in the nose-up direction (because the prop is "blowing" on the tail harder).
So, trim speed will often drop when you add power. Experiment yourself in the airplane to see the effect: Set the plane up in level flight, trimmed hands off to hold 80 kt, then add power to climb, and leave the stick alone and just watch what the airplane does. It will hunt up and down for a while, seeking, then settling down at it's original trim state, but now in a climb because the power was increased. But you'll notice the trimmed speed is no longer 80kt. It will be some knots lower, say, 75 kt. Reverse the effect for power reductions. A reduction in power for a tractor engine will result in higher trimmed speed when everything settles down. It's as if a passenger climbed from the front seat to the back seat when you add power, and vise versa.
As you get on top of this phenomenon, you will anticipate it and learn to add a slight amount of nose down trim when adding power to climb (assuming you want to maintain the same speed) in order to keep the airplane from seeking a slower trim speed than you originally set. This is important safety wise in situations like go-arounds where you are firewalling the throttle with the plane trimmed to its final approach speed. If you do nothing, and relaxed on the controls due to some other distraction, the power increase will reduce the trim speed and the pitch up will be more than that required to convert the extra power to climb. You might find yourself approaching stall in a high power climb situation if you weren't paying attention to pitch.

You always pitch down to gain airspeed and pitch up to slow down.  Remember, gravity is usually around 4x the strength of your plane at full throttle!
Trimming for proper airspeed in the pattern is a great way to simplify landing.  Instead of "high, low, fast, or slow?" you now only have "high or low", which can be managed with power.
Use the trim wheel to set your approach speed.  It can be the first thing to do going from downwind to base.  Then look.  You're either high or low.

"gravity is usually around 4x the strength of your plane at full throttle!" I'm probably dumb but what do you mean strength of your plane?? Like the lift? or what?

@AadirajAnil that would be thrust or forward propulsive force.  Gravity contributes to the sine of glide angle (below the horizon) × aircraft weight

"You always pitch down to gain airspeed and pitch up to slow down."  Nope.  Not if you plan to maintain a constant altitude.  To perform a level speed change you lead with power and trim as speed changes.

@MichaelHall the question is $obviously$ about trimming.  Your point is correct, what is the downvote for?  do I trim nose up or down to get that speed? (final line of question).

The DV is for the very reason I mentioned.  You don't "always" pitch to change airspeed.  (absolute statements can be gotchas, especially so when you make them bold!)

But since the question specifically asks about a climb or descent I will cut you some slack -  Get rid of the emphatic "always", or clarify controlling speed with pitch in a climb or descent and I will delete all comments and remove my DV...

@MichaelHall appreciate the comments.  If an aircraft is staticly stable pitch, pitch controls speed, power controls climb, level, or descent.  As I'm sure you know, pitch and power go hand and hand in controlling the aircraft.  (When I was learning aily and rud-rud were friends too).  We all have are ways, and hopefully we all land safe.

Again, nope.  You are thinking in simplistic absolutes.

But, for more advanced training, on less staticly stable aircraft, I totally agree.  A practical application for what you are talking about would be slowing from a pattern speed of 100 knots to approach speed of 65 knots in a 172.  Yes, absolutely, cut power and trim up (dropping flaps 10 will also raise the nose).

But "simplistic absolutes", if they work, need not be changed.  It does (however) depend on what one is flying.

No, it doesn't depend on what you are flying, or on stability either.

Guys, I think in the speed unstable region, which is during slow flight most often in an approach, speed is ultimately controlled by the pitch, and then your power or your altitude is mainly controlled by your power settings, but in the speed stable region, which is often when the aircraft has enough power and enough speed; a scenario is when we cruise, power controls speed and pitch controls altitude that’s why when you’re cruising if you point or pitch your airplane upwards to a certain nose up attitude you climb and  if you pull the power back your speed is gonna reduce in FAST FLIGHT

@Philoko you seem to be on the right track.  It's really a combination of pitch and power.  You can actually do both at the same time (yoke and throttle), for example, to capture a cruising altitude after climbing, THEN trim after you reach cruising speed.

Geez Robert, that's what i have been trying to tell you for at least a couple of years now... (eye roll)

In level flight portions of traffic pattern you set power, then trim to desired airspeed and if necessary, adjust power a bit to maintain speed and altitude.
In descent you again set power, trim for desired airspeed, and then control the rate of decent with power.
As Robert described in his answer, always trim nose up to reduce airspeed and nose down to increase airspeed. You must use the throttle simultaneously to keep the assigned altitude or proper rate of decent.
Stick/yoke should always be trimmed to feel neutral, in traffic pattern you are essentially trimming most of the time 
